# How to check whether a type is an enum in Kotlin?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

At runtime, I am trying to verify whether a particular `KClass<out Any>` is an enum type or not.

What is the best way to do so? Can this be done without relying on a particular runtime (e.g., JVM or JS)?

```
fun isEnum( type: KClass<out Any> ): Boolean
{
    ... ?
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Also a JVM-only solution, but a shorter one, using [`isSubClassOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/is-subclass-of.html):

```
fun isEnum(type: KClass<out Any>) = type.isSubclassOf(Enum::class)
```

Answer (score 1):

**JVM specific**

None of the solutions here where working for me (I had a `KType`) so I came up with another approach. Here is a solution for converting the `KClass` to a `KType` and then checking if the `KType` is an enum.

```
fun isEnum(kClass: KClass<out Any> ): Boolean {
    val kType :KType = kClass::class.createType()
    return (kType.javaType  as Class<*>).isEnum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for JVM, relying on the qualified type name.

```
fun isEnum( type: Kclass<out Any> ): Boolean
{
    return type.supertypes.any { t ->
        (t.classifier as KClass<out Any>).qualifiedName == "kotlin.Enum" }
}
```

However, this does not work for JS since `KClass::supertypes` is not available for that runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late to the party but if you want to check if an Any object is an Enum you could do it with an extension function. Which makes your code cleaner if you don't want to get the class etc.

```
fun Any?.isEnum(): Boolean {
    return this != null && this::class.isSubclassOf(Enum::class)
}
```